# Select para trazer registro específico de um id

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber como faço para trazer um registro específico de uma fk, sendo que tenho a tabela *hospedagem* e a tabela *consumo*
(com fk `codHospedagem`). Quando seleciono alguma hospedagem, clico no botão de consumo da minha tela consumo.

Preciso trazer no consumo, os registros de consumo daquela hospedagem que seleciono, pois meu select não está funcionando, só traz a linha vazia.
Abaixo o código:

```
SELECT c.codConsumo as Consumo,c.codHospedagem as Hospedagem , 
p.nomeProduto AS Produto, 
c.quantidade, c.valorConsumo, c.status 
FROM consumo c   
INNER JOIN  produto AS p ON p.codProduto = c.codProduto                   
INNER JOIN hospedagem AS H ON H.codHospedagem = C.codHospedagem                 
WHERE H.codHospedagem = c.codConsumo
ORDER BY c.codConsumo ;
```

Comment: Olá, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 2):

Verifique a sintaxe do `where` porque você está filtrando as hospedagens pelo código do consumo, e não da hospedagem relacionada ao consumo.

**Exemplificando:**

No seu código, `H.codHospedagem` se relaciona com `C.CodHospedagem`, então em seu `where` deve conter uma referência à **hospedagem** - *e não ao consumo*.

```
SELECT c.codConsumo as Consumo,c.codHospedagem as Hospedagem , 
p.nomeProduto AS Produto, 
c.quantidade, c.valorConsumo, c.status 
FROM consumo c   
INNER JOIN  produto AS p ON p.codProduto = c.codProduto                   
INNER JOIN hospedagem AS H ON H.codHospedagem = C.codHospedagem                 
WHERE H.codHospedagem = /*c.codConsumo*/
ORDER BY c.codConsumo ;
```

Comment: obg ismael! tentei com o where desta forma e me retornou todos os consumo que tenho na tabela: where   H.codHospedagem = c.codHospedagem

Comment: Preciso que me retorne todos os consumos de uma id específica.

Comment: @Lizy o que o ismael indicou é que deves colocar o ID assim: `WHERE H.codHospedagem = $id`

Comment: obg funcionou!!!